# Django and pytest, multiple databases, use only one database

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, pytest, pytest-django

I have 2 databases in my project:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': env.db('DEFAULT_DATABASE_URL'),
    'second': env.db('SECOND_DATABASE_URL'),
}
```

When I had only one database, then all tests that required access to the database passed fine, but when I connected the second one, then all tests began to fail with an error - `django.db.utils.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint`.

As I understand it, the test runs twice for each database and crashes because of this. Is there some way to tell pytest to only take one database for tests?

Example of one test:

```
@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_complaint_reasons(client: APIClient):
    reasons_count = 12
    Profile.create_batch(reasons_count)

    client.force_login(Factory())
    response = client.get(reverse('url'))
    assert response.status_code == status.HTTP_200_OK
    assert len(response.data) == reasons_count
    jsonschema.validate(response.data, ProfileComplaintReasonsSchema)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this mark instead:
`@pytest.mark.django_db(databases=['default', 'second'])`

But be careful with this because [it's still experimental](https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/database.html#tests-requiring-multiple-databases).